# Remove images (files) that were generated when using add_image_size()

Tags: images, customization

I have added an image size using this:

```
add_image_size('property-featured', 484, 393, true);
```

It's worked very well for the past year and has generated about 1GB of images in that size, but this image size is no longer needed. I want to clear up the images that have been created over the year in this size.

So far I have removed that line of code but it doesn't clean up the created images.

What is the correct way to remove those images?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found a plugin that does this for me: [Additional image sizes (zui)](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/additional-image-sizes-zui/)

> When you delete an image size that size will not be created for all NEW images you upload. 
>   However, images created for deleted sizes still exist on the server as well as the image attachment metadata for those sizes. 
>   This feature will physically delete those images from the server as well as the image attachment meta data for those sizes. 
>   Use this feature at your own risk. There is no undo.

**Update**

While the plugin worked wonders and did a lot of cleanup it couldnt cleanup the files left behind by images that had been removed from WordPress in the past. I used this home brew script to clean up some of the left over images:

```
<?php
$files = find_all_files("/home/****/public_html/wp-content/uploads");
$files2 = array();

foreach($files as $key => $file) {
    if(1 == preg_match("#150x\d+\.jpg$#", $file)) {
        $files2[] = $file;
        unlink($file);
    }elseif(1 == preg_match("#300x\d+\.jpg$#", $file)) {
        $files2[] = $file;
        unlink($file);
    }elseif(1 == preg_match("#\d+\x300.jpg$#", $file)) {
        $files2[] = $file;
        unlink($file);
    }elseif(1 == preg_match("#\d+\x150.jpg$#", $file)) {
        $files2[] = $file;
        unlink($file);
    }elseif(1 == preg_match("#\d+\x1024.jpg$#", $file)) {
        $files2[] = $file;
        unlink($file);
    }
}


print_r($files2);


function find_all_files($dir) 
{ 
    $root = scandir($dir); 
    foreach($root as $value) 
    { 
        if($value === '.' || $value === '..') {continue;} 
        if(is_file("$dir/$value")) {$result[]="$dir/$value";continue;} 
        foreach(find_all_files("$dir/$value") as $value) 
        { 
            $result[]=$value; 
        } 
    } 
    return $result; 
} 
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

I use http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/ to recreate my thumbnails, as far as I am aware it removes all image sizes then regenerates them. It could be a slow one depending on how many images + image sizes are reigstered.

Another way would be to do this via SSH and find them with a command like:

```
find ./uploads/*  -iname '*-484x393.*' -ls
```

Then run a command like:

```
find ./uploads/*  -iname '*-484x393.*' -exec rm {} \;
```

Please make sure you back up everything before running such a command.

Comment: At first I thought that was a good idea but when I looked into what data is stored it turned out that there is a whole heap of meta data stored in the DB for each resized image. Deleting the images this way will leave the data behind which is not what I'm after on a production site.

Comment: I took a glancing look into the WordPress meta tables etc and code base, and couldn't see what meta data you were talking about? Could you point me to what you were seeing? I might write a plugin over the weekend for this, as it's quite a nice little idea. :)

Comment: No need to make a plugin as there are a fair few already. One I've already mentioned. But to find the meta data I'm talking about: Find an image attachment ID. Then look in the postmeta table and take a look at all the rows that are attached to that attachment. One of the rows (cannot remember name) has a tonne of serialized data in it. That data contains paths to all the resized images and what resulting size they are.